# Dropdown or drop-down

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In web programming we use drop-down lists, but I'm not sure about the correct grammar. Wikipedia says "drop-down" when most frameworks uses "dropdown". Which one is correct ?

Comment: Why do you think one is "correct" and the other not?

Comment: e-mail or email? log in or login? website or web site? All are grammatically correct. My only suggestion would be to pick one and stick to it consistently across the project.

Comment: Please show a couple of examples of dictionary entries, and state which other dictionaries you've tried. If alternative spellings (and this is about orthography, nothing to do with grammar as more narrowly defined on ELU) are given, you have a choice of correct alternatives.

Comment: Just remember that to use `drop-down` as an identifier in most programming languages would be a syntax error, so `dropdown` is a clear choice there and that then might flow over to written english.

Comment: You usually can't just concatenate words in English. But there seem to be lots of exceptions (doorknob, dropout, framework,...). I guess some of those words "grew together" over time and got established as independent terms. However, drop-down is actually an abbreviation for drop-down menu (just like pop-up for pop-up window) so it might be "drop-down", which is also how Cambridge dictionary spells it.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends.
If you have discussions within the frameworks, you should use dropdown.
Otherwise, you probably should use drop-down for general grammar usage.

Comment: I imaging it's because DropDown would be the name of a class or some other structure, and in many languages '-' in invalid in a structure name. Framework documentation authors either are or are very close to the framework authors themselves. In any case Wikipedia has their own Manual of Style and an army of editors enforce it rigidly.

Comment: Every discussion takes place within something that could be called a framework, so it is not clear what role is played in this answer by the clause 'if you have discussions within the frameworks'.